How is the ground node location decided?
I'm very new to electrical engineering, and would like help in understanding how a node is decided to be declared as a ground node. Does the location of the ground node matter, and cause circuits to not work if not in a specific place?  In this circuit,

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
(I apologize for the crudity, I'm unsure of how else to design this)

Would the circuit not function the same if the ground were declared at, say, the trigger pin instead of the negative terminal of the power supply?

Theoretically, it is completely arbitrary (assuming the circuit is floating). But practically, it is usually connected to the negative of the main power supply to simplify calculations (and in case it is not floating but connected to an actual ground).

@EugeneSh. That makes sense, however I've seen websites stating that negative is not always ground, what do you think they mean by that?

Not sure without the actual citation, but sometimes there are more than a single source, so one might pick another reference point for example to make the circuit more "symmetrical" in terms of voltage values, or for some other simplifications.

If a single supply voltage is used, GND is usually connected to the negative terminal. For analog circuits a bipolar supply is often used (+15 V, -15 V). In this case the GND is connected to the connection of both supplies, so we have three terminals  (+15 V, GND, -15 V)

Another factor is that often there are many connections to the negative supply rail.  So using the ground symbol on the negative supply rail can simplify drawing the schematic as you can optionally use the ground symbol instead of showing connections to the negative supply everywhere.

@Uwe Thank you for explaining, this makes much more sense to me now. When dealing with ground, is its location chosen so that it always equals zero in comparison to the positive supply voltage, like with 9-volt batteries where the positive terminal equals +9 V from the negative terminal (if not damaged or old)? Correct me if I'm incorrect, but since some ICs have ground pins, I'd assume said pins' voltages have to equal 0 so as not to damage the IC?

I presume you understand this already, but just in case I'll re-iterate. The "ground" in a floating circuit is a mathematical abstraction and serves as a reference point only. Voltages are differences in potential between two points, so it does not really matter which point you designate to be a reference point and have a potential of zero, the differences (i.e. the voltage drops on different components) will remain the same.

@EugeneSh. Thank you for the information, and I did not completely understand ground before. I'm still very new to the concepts of electrical engineering, the help is much appreciated. (Edit: Question, if I have another question, should I simply post another, or edit this one? I'm still new to stack exchange as well.)

@RetroBoltDev You should ask a new question. Edits are only when you're clarifying the existing question.

In most electronics, "Ground" is simply a name we apply to some point in a circuit to indicate that we will use that point as the zero volt reference - it is where we put our black meter lead when measuring voltages elsewhere in the circuit.  It would probably be better to call this point "Common" or "Reference", but this misuse of the term "Ground" is so well established that we are stuck with it.
This Reference Ground is often the most negative point in the circuit, but may be the most positive point, or, in many analog circuits, it will be the mid-point of the power supply.
This misuse of the term "Ground" does not imply any connection to The Earth, and does not have any special properties (some beginners seem to think that the Ground symbol sucks all the electrons out of the circuit - it does not!)

Calling a node ground is nothing more than a name. It's the same as if you called the node Vee, or COM, or Vcc, or George. What name you give it has no impact on the circuit--it just may make things hard to understand if you start calling it Vcc.

Thank you for helping me understand this. If possible, what do you mean by "may make things hard to understand"?

@RetroBoltDev "Vcc" is usually the name for the supply voltage, the "opposite" of ground.
